# Angular vs React НЕ для SPA

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

Подскажите пжл люди кто хорошо знаком с Angular и React - какой из двух лучше подходит для разработки, когда речь идет НЕ о SPA, а когда рендеринг происходит на стороне сервера и на клиенте осуществляется интерактивность уже над тем HTML, который прилетел с сервера? Что быстрее в плане разработки и менее трудозатратно, да и вообще лучше именно для таких целей, которые описал?

Comment: Для тех целей, что Вы описали - jQuery

Comment: jQuery - не хватает для создания гибкой интерактивности.

Comment: @Александр, что вы понимаете под _гибкой интерактивностью_?

Comment: под гибкой интерактивностью подразумеваю - строить сложные интерфейсы и эффективно, быстро работать с DOM-ом на стороне клиента, без километровых портянок jQyery, построенных на реагировании по событиям.

Comment: @Александр, портянки можно писать с любой технологией включая ангуляр и реакт

Comment: HTML без шаблонов Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вашего конкретного случая не имеет ровным счетом никакого значения, какой из двух фрэймворков вы выберете. Они оба вполне сносно подойдут для ваших целей.

Более того, вряд ли вы найдете столь квалифицированных специалистов, которые смогут адекватно и в достаточной степени объективно сравнить их. В силу того, что технологии относительно новые.

Выше я подразумевал, что мы сравниваем React-15.0.* и Angular-2.*

Для меня основным недостатком первого является то, что html код незаметно перемещается в javascript, что усложняет совместную работу над проектом низкоквалифицированных сотрудников, которые, к примеру, знают только html.

Основным недостатком второго, пока, является достаточно невнятная документация (хотя это уж точно исключительно субъективно).